# Link html para o ficheiro javascript não funciona

Tags: javascript, html5, visual-studio, arquivo

Boas estou a tentar este código de javaScript no meu html.

```
let slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 5000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

Mas quando chamo o js ele não funciona apenas da se eu pegar no codigo e o colocar dentro do html entre < scripts >.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Projeto de ai.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="imagens/icon.png">
    <title>Projeto de AI</title>
</head>
<body >
  <div class="slideshow-container">

    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
      <img src="imagens/imagem1.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="texto">Caption Text</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
      <img src="imagens/imagem2.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="texto">Caption Two</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
      <img src="imagens/imagem3.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="texto">Caption Three</div>
    </div>
    
    </div>
<script src="/Projeto de ai.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

alguém me pode ajudar a entender o porque?

Comment: `<script src="/Projeto de ai.js"...>` com essa tag ele vai buscar o teu script na "raiz" do projeto, por causa da barra, veja se está no lugar certo... se estiver na mesma pasta da página html, remova a barra... sugiro também evitar espaços no nome

Comment: Para o responder precisaríamos conhecer o path completo dos arquivos html e js. Também precisaríamos sabem como está carregando o arquivo html, se é através de um servidor ou se a carga é feita diretamente no servidor

Comment: Importante sempre que postar uma pergunta com código, fornecer um [mcve] em vez do código já aplicado ao seu uso específico. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Acesse o console do navegador aperta F12 e veja qual mensagem de erro está aparecendo. Se o arquivo nao foi localizado você vai ver uma mensagem de "NOT FOUND", então provavelmente o caminho que você está colocando no atributo src pode estar errado.

**Uma dica**, evite espaços nos nome dos arquivos, quando for pra ter espaço use traço no lugar, por exemplo. Em vez de "Meu Arquivo De Testes.js", salve com o "meu-arquivo-de-testes.js" ou "meu_arquivo_de_testes.js"

Answer (score -1):

Tens que escrever desse jeito e verificar se o arquivo está na pasta "raiz" se estiver na pasta "raiz" podes escrever desse jeito:

```
<script src="/arquivo.js"></script>
```

Caso esteja em uma pasta deves fazer desse jeito para adicionar o caminho da pasta:

```
<script src="nomedapasta/arquivo.js"></script>
```

Obs: podes fazer a remoção do "/" deixando src="arquivo.js"
E remover o espaçamento no nome do arquivo a forma mais acertada seria
"nome-do-arquivo.js" ou "nome_do_arquvo.js".

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).